# Unable to build material components for web data table

Tags: datatables, material-design, material-components, material-components-web

I'm using material components for my web application. I'm new to node and npm and just wanted to use this framework for CSS/Themes in my web application.

I followed this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-web/#3) and was doing okay until I added the data table component. Below is the error that I'm getting.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle aliweb@1.0.0~prebuild: aliweb@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle aliweb@1.0.0~build: aliweb@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle aliweb@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle aliweb@1.0.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\User\Projects\Workspace\spring-tool-suite-4-4.3.0.RELEASE\aliweb\src\main\resources\static\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.25\lib;C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.25\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle aliweb@1.0.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\User\Projects\Workspace\spring-tool-suite-4-4.3.0.RELEASE\aliweb\src\main\resources\static
10 silly lifecycle aliweb@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack --mode production' ]
11 silly lifecycle aliweb@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle aliweb@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: aliweb@1.0.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid aliweb@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\User\Projects\Workspace\spring-tool-suite-4-4.3.0.RELEASE\aliweb\src\main\resources\static
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v10.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error aliweb@1.0.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the aliweb@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Has anyone come across this same error? Or is it a bug in the data table component.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: The error log message that you provided isn't helpful to investigate the issue. It would be great if you can provide a step by step things that you tried and full log error.

Please see this full example on Glitch of MDC Data Table: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/flat-spike

Comment: Actually I solved the issue by deleting all material components and installing the material-components web as a whole instead of installing individual components.